# Divs not centered on different media queries

Tags: html, css, image, text, center

I am quite new in web development. I have built a website and the problem is in the `portfolio` section. I cannot manage to center on all devices the images and the text.

Website URL: [alextodea.net](http://alextodea.net)

Thanks a lot!

Relevant code. The CSS used for media queries :  alextodea.net/css/style.css

Comment: Please add your relevant code here.

Comment: i tried to edit it but it says something about 4 blocks. They do not allow me to add the code.

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: I added the path to the relevant css. I think that i mixed everything up. Should i start doing the media queries again? I feel frustrated. I have to built a portfolio internship so that i can get an internship because it is required for my school and i am running out of time :(

Comment: You need to copy-paste the **relevant** code in your question so that other people can help you. Just a link to your website isn't very helpful. Do this: (1) edit your question. (2) Click the Snippet button < >. (3) paste your html, css and javascript in the relevant fields and click "Insert". (4) Save your edits.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css, this will center the image and text in devices below 980px.

```
@media screen and (max-width:990px) {
#workd .thumb, #workd .description {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.col-xs-12.col-md-8.description.block.more { padding-left:0; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it's not working...still nothing centered.

Comment: That should work, I am unable to see the latest code in your website. Have you added it in you live website ?

Comment: the code that you recommended me is at the bottom of the page (alextodea.ent/css/style.css)

Comment: Add a } before @media screen and (max-width:990px)

Comment: You can check your website now ib your phone or any device to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this rules in bootstrap.css
in line 1616 remove the

```
.row {
    /* margin-right: 78px; */
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

and in style.css line 340 remove padding right.

```
 @media (max-width: 767px)
.block.more {
    /* padding-right: 75px; */
}
```

Then i think that will work fine.